# android : how can i build my application that work on devices with Intel CPU?

Tags: android, arm, cpu, intel, abi

how can i build my application that work on devices with Intel CPU ? my application work on devices with arm technology but when i try to install my app on device with Intel CPU it`s show this message :

> Devicenot compatible

and this message on log :

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]

this is my project build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled  false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager        to use this dependency.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.0'
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
}
```

i use android studio IDE for my project.
how can i build APK file that work on devices with both arm and Intel CPU`s ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use gradle splits to allow your app to be easily built for different platforms. More read on it [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-ABIs-Splits)

Comment: i want to have same APK for two platform

Comment: i am afraid it is not possible to make a single APK file run on both x86 and ARM architectures, since the APK has to be built differently for each of those. https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/creating-an-x86-and-arm-apk-using-the-intelr-compiler-and-gnu-gcc this might be an interesting read but i have no idea if it is suitable for your case

Answer (score 0):

i finally find problem ! i remove this library

> 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

and after that my application run on device with Intel cpu