# Play store is showing 0 supported devices with same code

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I have tried to upload my app's new version (ex:v1.0.4) to play store and it is showing 0 supported devices.

For testing, I rollbacked my old version (ex: v1.0.2), changed only version code/name in gradle file and tried to upload the apk again. It is showing 0 supported devices too.

Few days ago, that version (v1.0.2) supported more than 3000 devices.

My question is why the play store is showing 2 different results for 2 exactly same code apks (only version code and name are different).

Is it because google policy changed or I updated my gradle and android studio?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: chk soln provided against your gradle file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308560/supported-android-devices-0-devices

Comment: I already checked the all solutions and made it work. The same code is not working from today

Comment: @imudin07 same thing is happening to me .I uploaded an apk in the morning and now by changing only version code ,it is showing 0 device supported . Any luck ?

Comment: @SujitYadav Really? Unfortunately no luck yet. I feel like its google issue. they changed the play store publishing site recently

Comment: there are lots of 0 device supported issue within 2-3 hours on stackoverflow

Comment: Yeah?  seems like a common issue. I hope we will find a solution

Comment: @SujitYadav See the answer, it worked for me

Comment: @imudin07 happened with google and wasted 4 hour of my life :D

Comment: Yep -wasted 4 hours of my time as well and a lot of hair loss!!!! I expect more from Google!

Comment: Just uploaded a new APK and it is showing 0 supported devices. Is anyone else having the issue as for now?. Anyway - assuming my APK IS supported 0 devices (somehow...) , Doing a partially staged rollout (let's say for 10%) should be zero-dangerous, as new users will still see the previous APK, and the 10% "chosen ones" just won't get the new updated APK. Am I right? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to be a display issue: if you check the device catalog, supported devices are displayed properly, and once rollout takes place, the "i" icon next to the APK also shows the correct figure.

Google has confirmed the issue in chat, so I'm positive a fix is in the pipe.

Comment: Oh you mean even it shows 0 supported devices, I should rollout and then I will check it after?

Comment: That's right, roll out, then check the Device Catalog and the App Releases screen's APK info.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: if it will still show 0, can I remove that new version and back to current one?

Comment: If by then it still shows 0, _and_ the Device Catalog says so too, you can start having doubts that there is actually something wrong :) Also, clear cache - can't go wrong with that.

Comment: Yes. if there is something wrong,  it is possible to remove that release and back to previous one, right?

Comment: Perfect! It is showing the same amount of devices as previous one after rollout :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZalánMeggyesi thats why i  love stackoverflow

Comment: ok just confirmed the answers as I had a new version release today. It shows zero devices. Then save the draft -> review and publish. In the Published part the 'i' next to apk on the right hand side does indeed display the right device information.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late to answer, I face the same problem. With setting all users-features as `false`, play store still shows zero devices supported.

Here is solution, hope will help someone

```
   <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

Also

<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Hope it help.

Comment: I used your suggestion play store still showing 0 supported devices, incompatible for devices :(