# why my released apk has supported devices : 0 status on google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have tried to publish my app on google play for 3 times ,all of published apk had supported devices:0 status
I have read all topics( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308560/supported-android-devices-0-devices) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045520/play-store-is-showing-0-supported-devices-with-same-code) ) which exist on Stackoverflow and i did whatever programmers advised but it didn't work

this is a screen shot from console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAF7b.jpg)

and here is my manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Flashlight_widget"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.setParameters" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.Camera.flash"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application

        android:name=""com.Flashlight_widget""
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/FlashLight_Shake_Widget"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity
            android:name="com.Flashlight_widget".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.Flashlight_widget.FlashLightIntentService"
            android:exported="false"
            />
        <receiver android:name="com.Flashlight_widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.Flashlight_widget.ResultActivity"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.Flashlight_widget.MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.Flashlight_widget.MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.Flashlight_widget"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

From `Android` look at `Gradle Scripts` then `build.gradle(Module: app)` and see if your minSdkVersion from Manifest matches the one from `build.gradle`.

Change `android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer` with `android.hardware.sensor.ACCELEROMETER`

Delete this:

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />`
 from Manifest and change the minSdkVersion from `build.gradle(Module: app)`.